# Does any RTOS support SMP scheduling?

Tags: rtos, freertos, smp

We have a project in which the SOC has multi-core like ARM Cortex-R8; so we want an open-source RTOS that supports SMP scheduling.  But it seems that no RTOS supports SMP, at least from its official release version.

Could anyone give the suggestion about it?

Comment: Your title does not reflect the question you start off asking for _any_ RTOS, then narrow the scope to _open-source_.

Comment: ERIKA Enterprise version 3 (https://github.com/evidence/erika3) has native support for SMP. However, code for Cortex-R will be released only in the next months...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is neither true that *no RTOS* has SMP support, or even that no *open-source* RTOS has support.

The open-source eCOS supports SMP (Symmetric Multiprocessing).  http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/ref/kernel-smp.html

Also NuttX http://nuttx.org/doku.php?id=wiki:nxinternal:smp

In the non open-source world, choices are wider, such as QNX Neutrino, and VxWorks.

Comment: Yes,  thanks for your reply. you are right. I should take the "open source" into the title to narrow the scope. And, your answer is very helpful to me, thank you.